# Vue2 object not setted

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to get list of data from server and show it, but looks like Vue do not see new data(not make  them reactive)

```
      Vue.component('Videos', {
            template:
                `
                <div>
                    <div v-for="video in videos" v-text="video.name">
                    </div>
                <div>
            `,
            data() {
                return {
                    videos: {},
                }
            },
            methods: {
                getVideos() {
                    axios.get('/admin/videos?token='+localStorage.getItem('auth_token'))
                        .then(function(response) {
                            this.videos = response.data.videos;
                        }).catch(function(errors){
                            this.error = errors.data;
                    })
                },
            },
            created: function () {
                this.getVideos();
            }

        });

    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
});
```

Also I try to use

`Object.keys(response.data.videos).forEach(
     key => this.$set(this.videos, key, response.data.videos[key])
);`

and 
`this.videos = Object.assign({}, this.videos, response.data.videos)`

but it's still not work for me. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loosing context in both `then` and `catch` callbacks. As the result, you are setting `window.videos` variable (global) instead of your component instance `videos` property (same with `error`).

Simple fix is to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which preserve lexical binding:

```
methods: {
    getVideos() {
        axios.get('/admin/videos?token='+localStorage.getItem('auth_token'))
            .then(response => {
                this.videos = response.data.videos;
            }).catch(errors => {
                this.error = errors.data;
        })
    },
},
```

Comment: Thanks it help. But why I can't write it without that ES2015 response => ??? 

from axios docs 
`axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });`

Comment: Because when you use anonymous function `function (response) { console.log(response); }` execution context is global object (`window`). It's fine if you want to `console.log`, but in your case you want to set property of your component, so you need to have proper `this`. `.then(function (response) { this.videos = response.data.videos; }.bind(this))` would work. Or you could also save reference to this and use it inside callback: `const self = this; ... .then(function (response) { self.videos = response.data.videos; })`.